# does EXP, PG and JP rewards change with a Ba'al's Level?

Tags: bravely-second

So i defeated Ba'al iv Goldie which came to me at Level 18 but i reduced it level down to 1 to find out if it had any quirks like the other Ba'als i defeated.

with only 1,000 HP against a party of Level 30's it was a quick battle but i was surprised to find that i scored over 200 JP as a reward (EXP and PG i wasn't too concerned).

So i am wondering if all Ba'al's will reward me the same EXP, PG and JP regardless of what level i reduce them down to with my ship?

Comment: I fixed the answer after completing my data gathering, so I hope the information is useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: **Yes, the Maximum Ba'al level does affect PG, EXP, or JP earned**, while the current level does not. This means a level 30 Ba'al gives more exp than a level 25 Ba'al, but reducing their level to 1 does not change the reward of those 2 Ba'als.  Also different Ba'als give different rewards, just like monsters.

Chompillionaire Ba'als are all around `10000 PG, 143 EXP, and 12 JP` and have such a low HP, don't waste your time firing your ships at one. A level 30 Chomp Ba'al has just under 600 hp, and the reason for killing them is PG.

I have tested between levels 1-5 and they all ended up with the same amount, so the current/reduced Ba'al level does not affect the rewards (this is testing with similar level Ba'als).

To give an idea, I will give a few Ba'als that I have fought that were all reduced to level 1.

`27@1` means they started at level 27 and were reduced to level 1.

Firstborn

`27@1: 3091 PG, 5081 EXP, 301 JP`

`30@1: 3275 PG, 5494 EXP, 330 JP`

`34@1: 3520 PG, 6045 EXP, 369 JP`

Turtledove

`24@1: 1938 PG, 3112 EXP, 272 JP`

`25@1: 1979 PG, 3204 EXP, 282 JP`

Ba'al vi; Snowcap

`60@1: 3408 PG, 6418 EXP, 621 JP`

Neo Snowcap

`34@1: 4030 PG, 7397 EXP, 369 JP`

I can add more if it makes everyone feel better about the data, but essentially the only thing that affects the rewards are the Maximum Ba'al level (or the level it started on) and the Ba'al you fight.